# On which site should I ask about HTML/CSS questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question: I want know how to check out other's CSS code, for example, [this website](http://jtcollin.com/chapter4/pacific4/index.html). (Yes, it is homework.)

Which Stack Exchange site should I ask on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**So you want to check out other websites' CSS code?**

That question wouldn't really be accepted on any site. The answer can easily be found by searching Google. Just right-click on the website, click "view page source" *or similar*, find the `.css` file(s) and you can see the CSS file(s) the site is using.

For example, I did just that on this page, and found this in the source:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/content/stackexchangemeta/all.css?v=209f88f34112">
```

Just click on it and it will bring you to the file https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/stackexchangemeta/all.css?v=209f88f34112 . Note that many sites minify the code, so it makes it really unreadable, but then you could search Google again for a "prettify" tool.

---

**When you have issues with your own HTML/CSS that you've written, then you can most likely ask on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)**

Read this whole link before asking there please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Especially acknowledge this part:

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work
>   you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the
>   difficulty you are having solving it.

As an example, take a look at this good question: [Make top div as wide as the div below it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264013/make-top-div-as-wide-as-the-div-below-it)

It shows the relevant code: the HTML and CSS

It describes the issue. And even helps further explain it by posting images.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I have solved the problem, a thousand thanks!